# Insert into table many values

Tags: mysql, sql

When inserting into query, I know I need to use:

`insert into TABLE (company, type) VALUES ('Ford','Cars')` - this creates one row.

However, what if I have many values for the fields? 
For example: Fields - Ford, BMW, Nestle and Values - Cars, Cars, Food

How can I put this into query? Note that I have a long list to insert, so don't really want to type to much within a query.

Thank you heaps ;-)

Comment: You could find a solution in any of google search's first page results.

Comment: I adore this way of socialising, mate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple rows in a single `insert`:

```
insert into TABLE (company, type)
    VALUES ('Ford1','Cars'),
           ('Ford2','Cars'),
           ('Ford3','Cars');
```